# EF Core 5 - many to many with composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I start to work with newest EF Core 5.0.4. I am making relationship between two entities Recipe and Article with connetion table as RecipeArticle. Below the mapping:

```
 public class RecipeMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Recipe>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Recipe> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.HasMany(x => x.Articles)
                   .WithMany(x => x.Recipes)
                   .UsingEntity<RecipeArticle>(
                        j => j
                            .HasOne(pt => pt.Article)
                            .WithMany(t => t.RecipeArticles)
                            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ArticleId),
                        j => j
                            .HasOne(pt => pt.Recipe)
                            .WithMany(p => p.RecipeArticles)
                            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.RecipeId),
                        j =>
                        {
                            j.HasKey(t => new { t.ArticleId, t.RecipeId });
                            j.Property(x => x.Optional).HasDefaultValueSql("0");
                        });
        }
    }
```

When I run migration I get following error:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
> services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
> The entity type 'RecipeArticle' requires a primary key to be defined.
> If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in
> 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

The error specify that I did not specify primary key for my conncetion table RecipeArticle however it is set above **j.HasKey(t => new { t.ArticleId, t.RecipeId });**

However to make it more clear I did anothre mapping for my RecipeArticle entity and specify key one more time

```
public class RecipeArticleMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<RecipeArticle>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RecipeArticle> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => new { x.RecipeId, x.ArticleId });
        }
    }
```

However the error remains the same.
I tried to follow [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key).

Does anyone had similar issue ?

@Edit:
I added the same mapping for Article and still the error message is the same.

Comment: Did you try what exception advices:  `call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'`?

Comment: Just tried, the error message is the same

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in similar code. You should give a [mcve] for us to be able to reproduce it exactly.